# How do i configure vscode live preview for simple wordpress style.css edits?

Tags: css, wordpress, visual-studio-code

I'm editing CSS on a very basic wordpress site on a remote server, using vscode. I'm interested in linking vscode to my browser window and having the site reload every time I save changes to style.css.

I've successfully installed the Live Preview vscode extension, and can see any saved changes to style.css when I manually refresh my browser, but browser isn't auto reloading on style.css save. What have I missed?

Answer (score 0):

install  BrowserSync globaly :

```
npm install -g browser-sync
```

then start the service :

```
browser-sync start --proxy "your-wordpress-site-url" --files "style.css"
```